# qApp->installTranslator() and tr didn't translate?

Tags: c++, qt, translation

I'm trying to change my application language dynamically  :

```
void MainWindow::ChangeEvent(QEvent *event, QString *language)
{
    if (event->type() == QEvent::LanguageChange) {
        RetranslateInterface(language);
        //ui.retranslateUi(this);
    }
    QWidget::changeEvent(event);
}

void MainWindow::RetranslateInterface(QString *language) {

    QString lang = language->remove(2, language->length());
    lang = lang.toLower();
    qDebug()<<"lang"<<lang;

    lang = "qt_" + lang + ".qm";
    qDebug()<<"lang"<<lang;

    if ( Translator )
        qApp->removeTranslator( Translator );

    qDebug()<<"Translator->load( lang)"<< Translator->load( QApplication::applicationDirPath()+"/"+ lang);
    qApp->installTranslator( Translator );

    //qDebug()<<"tr >>>>"<<qApp->translate("MainWindow","my english text");
    setWindowTitle(tr("my english text"));


}

void MainWindow::Slot_ChLangue(QAction* Trigaction)
{

    QString Selectedlanguage = Trigaction->text();
    qDebug()<<"selected language"<<Selectedlanguage;

    if (!Selectedlanguage.isEmpty()) {

        QEvent *translate = new QEvent(QEvent::LanguageChange);
        ChangeEvent(translate, &Selectedlanguage);
    }
}
```

"qt_*.qm" was loaded but `setWindowTitle(tr("my english text"));` didn't set the appropriate text

I tried this in the main function it didn't work either:

```
QTranslator translator;
       if(QFile::exists(QApplication::applicationDirPath()+"/qt_fr.qm"))
       qDebug()<<"loaded"<<translator.load(QApplication::applicationDirPath()+"/qt_fr.qm");
       app.installTranslator(&translator);
       qDebug()<<"out en français"<<app.tr("my english text");
```

I get always "my english text" in english.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the content of your .qm file? At least the line which contains a translation of "my english text" as well as the surrounding lines

Comment: Actually, the .ts file would be more helpful

Comment: I think that I miss understood the approach: I thought that .qm file act like a dictionary and do all the work for me :(, the .qm file is supposed to contain the translation of all my strings, am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding your latest comment:

There is no predefined Dictionary, you need to translate the strings yourself (or have someone else translate them).

In order to do this, you need the following steps:

- Have tr() calls in your code
- Add something like `TRANSLATIONS += qt_fr.ts` to your .pro file
- Call `lupdate -verbose <yourprofile>.pro` in order to create an XML-structured .ts file which contains the texts which shall be translated
- Call `linguist qt_fr.ts` in order to start Qt Linguist and easily translate strings
- Generate the .qm file from Qt Linguist or using `lupdate`
- Run the application

There is a tutorial on using translations [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/linguist-hellotr.html).

Comment: thank you for your response, am under windows and am working with QtCreator so how can I do step 3, 4 and 5 ?  sorry am newbie.

Comment: If your Qt's binary folder (or `%QTDIR%\bin`) is added to your PATH-Variable, you can just open the command line at the specified location (e.g. right-click the `sources` folder in Qt Creator in your project and select "Open Command Window Here" or something like that) and type in the commands

Comment: I get my qt_fr.qm generated from .ts successfully and I run my application : only `qApp->translate` works and `tr` don't

Comment: @TimMeyer: I'm sure, in the 2nd last step you meant  
Generate the .qm file from QT Linguist using `lrelease` ?